# svn: E000111: Unable to connect to a repository at URL

Tags: linux, unix, svn

Please help me to rid out this problem, when I am trying to checkout, update, commit then I got these two errors.

> 1. svn: E000111: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
> 2. svn: E000111: Can't connect to host : Connection refused

Answer (score 2):

Connection refused generally means there is no service listening on that port.

Either the svn daemon is down or the port number you're providing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is the svn server running?

run this on the server (linux)

```
sudo svnserve -d --foreground -r /path/to/repos/root
```